# What is this stitch option on my Euro Pro Deluxe Denim & Silk

Tags: sewing-machine

Curious about this odd "offset" stitch on my sewing machine, does it have a name? When would it be used?

It's under the "stretch" heading, so I gather it would be used on stretchy fabrics, but I haven't been able to find any info about it in the manual or on stitch explainers online.[image: image showing offset stitch image, labeled I on the machine]

Answer (score 1):

The machines I used in school had a stitch under that name which was a narrow zigzag, almost a straight line.

The easy option is to try out the stitch on several kinds of fabric, and see what the stitch looks like and what happens when you stretch the fabric.

Comment: To me, the random nature of it looks like someone at Euro Pro trolling users because they were told to come up with yet one more pattern, There's nothing that makes it particularly suited to any real purpose (or even attractive). I couldn't find anything on the Internet that had an explanation, or even a picture of a machine with this stitch option. This answer is a good practical approach.